# How to split a string that doesn't have a separator in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, foundation

I'm looking to split this string in 4 parts. So far i'm only able to split it using `components(separatedBy:)` method. However i want i also to last word `teamId4` into 2 parts where i can get `teamId` and `4` the number. All the solutions i have looked at always have separators in them like string having either spaces, lines, full stops etc which makes it quite easy. How can i achieve this output `player23`, `8`, `teamId`, `4`

```
var player = "player23_8_chelseaId4"

var splittedString: [String] {
    let stringArray = player.components(separatedBy: "_")
    let playerID = stringArray[0]
    let playerIndex = stringArray[1]
    let team = stringArray[2]
    // Would like "4" as the last string in the array
    let array = [playerID, playerIndex, team]
    return array
}
```

This is the output so far

```
["player23", "8", "chelseaId4"]
```

Desired output would be

```
["player23", "8", "chelseaId", "4"]
```

Comment: Is it always "Id" before the number? What if the last part is "A123B456"?

Comment: The format is static. I'm always going to receive the data in that format

Comment: Nah, `23` is always included along with the players name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Regular Expression solution.

In the pattern the 4 pairs of parentheses represent the 4 captured strings, `\\w+` means one or more word characters. The separators are the two underscore characters and the `Id` string in which the latter is captured, too.

```
func splittedString(from player : String) throws -> [String] {
    var result = [String]()
    let pattern = "^(\\w+)_(\\w+)_(\\w+Id)(\\w+)$"
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: player, range: NSRange(player.startIndex..., in: player)) {
        for i in 1..<match.numberOfRanges {
            result.append(String(player[Range(match.range(at: i), in: player)!]))
        }
    }
    return result
}

let player = "player23_8_chelseaId4"
let splitted = try splittedString(from: player) // ["player23", "8", "chelseaId", "4"]
```

If you want only `chelsea` without `Id` change the pattern to `"^(\\w+)_(\\w+)_(\\w+)Id(\\w+)$"`

Answer (score 1):

```
var player = "player23_8_chelseaId4"

var splittedString: [String] {
    let stringArray = player.components(separatedBy: "_")
    let playerID = stringArray[0]
    let playerIndex = stringArray[1]
    let team = stringArray[2]

    let temp = team.components(separatedBy: "Id")
    // Would like "4" as the last string in the array
    let array = [playerID, playerIndex,"\(temp[0])Id" , temp[1]]
    return array
}

print(splittedString) // ["player23", "8", "chelseaId", "4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the "Id" string after every team name? So you could search for the substring Id and cut the string after it.